Multiple QR codes on Apple Wallet Pass
I want to show multiple QR codes on my apple wallet pass so that user can swipe them horizontally and access them through a single pass. As per documentation, I passed an array of barcodes in pass.json but it is still showing 1 QR code out of multiple items passed. What else can be done to achieve this behaviour on pass?
I added barcodes as following:
"barcodes": [
    {
      "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
      "message": "QR Code 1: https://example.com/code1",
      "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1",
      "altText": "QR Code 1"
    },
    {
      "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
      "message": "QR Code 2: https://example.com/code2",
      "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1",
      "altText": "QR Code 2"
    }
  ]

I expected pass to show up with all the QR codes, but it is only showing one QR code.

A pass can only display a single barcode. The barcodes property in the pass.json file specifies an array of barcodes to support different devices (watchOS devices cannot show Code 128 barcodes, for example).
From the documentation

Pass.Barcode - An array of objects that represent possible barcodes on a pass. The system uses the first displayable barcode for the device.

You can use the groupingIdentifier &  passTypeIdentifier properties to have multiple passes of a particular type displayed as a group.
